# Orthogonal projection of $v=(x,y)$ on $x=y$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection

I would like to find the orthogonal projection of a vector $v=(x,y)$ on $\beta: x=y$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$. I know that a basis for $\beta$ is $B=\{e_1+e_2=(1,1)\}$. The vector decomposition of a general vector $v$ is $v=\langle v, e_1\rangle \cdot e_1+\langle v, e_2\rangle \cdot e_2$. How can I proceed in finding the orthogonal projection?

Comment: $\newcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}\newcommand{\w}{\mathbf{w}}$Use the fact that the orthogonal projection of a vector $\v$ in the direction of a vector $\w$ is given by $$\color{blue}{\boxed{\operatorname{proj}_{\w}\v = \frac{\langle \v,\w\rangle}{\langle \w,\w\rangle}\w}}.$$(Note that $\w=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ for your case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you normalise the vector $(1,1)$, thereby getting $\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)$. Then, for each $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, the projection will be$$\left\langle(x,y),\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)\right\rangle\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)=\left(\frac{x+y}2,\frac{x+y}2\right).$$